# JavaScript API SDK security

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, restful-authentication

I have developed an API for my new service and am in process of developing SDKs (php, ruby and JavaScript) for this API.

Some of the calls to API are open to public, but some require API key and API secret. My question is, how do I make sure that people can hide their key and secret from world while using JavaScript API.

I would Imagine the call something like:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url:'http://api.domain.com/v1/display/',
    data: {offset:0, limit:0, apiKey:'apikeynotlikelogin',apiSecret:'apisecretlikepassword'},
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

But almost everyone these days know that if they open firebug or even simplier ctrl+shift+j in chrome, they can see the code together with all information above. I have considered many options, but it seems to me like there is just no way how to hide apiKey and apiSecret on front-end.

Any suggestions? There must be a way Im sure.

Thanks!

EDIT:

Thanks everyone for answers and trying to solve the issue. Here are some of the answers and why is still not what I need:

1. Using domain name in the request to make sure its from the correct client.
   This is valid suggestion, but still could be quite easily faked
2. Generating unique key for each call
   This seems to be more advanced, but again I found it not usable for my case. I need to authorize the "App" (thats what people register in system in order to get credentials and authorize to API) because users will have different levels of privacy set and according to those clients will be served with result.

So If I cam make client to first call "handshake" to get the session unique key, but then again (either in handshake or next request), client has to send his apiKey and apiSecret in order to authorize to API and get the correct result (according to policies etc.) So at the end, it is exactly the same as without the handshake request, anyone who knows the apiKey and apiSecret could first call handshake and then the authorization.
Hope it makes sense

Comment: There isn't much value in having both an API key and an API secret on the client side. This is actually very insecure, as both of these values are not only visible to the client, but can also be used to crack the algorithm that compares the two.

Comment: @Austin If I wouldn't know its visible to everyone I wouldn't be asking this question. But I am asking how to make sure that it is not visible. Also I don't see any grounds why there wouldn't be a value for using api key and secret, it is like standard login, just for API, so many APIs using it (amazon etc.) I don't thik its just useless... And I have no idea what are you referring to as "cracking algorith that compares the two". Its standard login. You provide key and password and see if its matches in database...

Comment: Yes, I was just reiterating on the comment that you made in your question - that they _are in fact visible to the client_. I don't have a full answer to your question, but was only commenting to provide my experience when faced with a similar problem. I took a similar route to @Pascal, by checking the origin of the request. From my experience, the client side can only do so much in terms of authentication.

Comment: Your API should distribute one time keys that are only usable within the individual user session. You then store these keys on the server side and check them against user session and/or other user credentials when used. Each API call should return a new key that can be used and delete all references to previously distributed ones for the same user session. These keys should also expire within a short period of time, only be distributed through SSL and be linked with other user data you can check against. Not perfect, but it's secure enough in most cases.

Comment: On the topic of the "algorithm cracking", I had a bit of a mix-up with the term "secret" which is the common variable name of a unique random string added to a value before it is encrypted. - this isn't the case here.

Comment: @TildalWave Yes I was considering the same approach, but more im thinking about it, more I cannot find the security in it. Client still has to use appkey and appsecret, because by authorizing the result of api differs (user privacy policy etc.). So if I make one extra call to get session unique key, I still have to authorize somewhere there and its the time when anyone who has the credentials could do so. So at the end it is basically just one more call, but doesnt make dfference. Im gonna update my question with example

Comment: How do you serve initial contents? If they would be generated by the same CGI that handles your API calls, then that 'would have some security in it' as you put it, if not, then this approach is meaningless by having to resort to an additional call that would obviously have to bypass any such security measures for it to even work. Asking differently, can you generate the first exchange key when you're creating a user session?

Comment: @TildalWave In PHP it works pretty simple. You make curl request, include your apikey and secret and send request. If you authorize you will get result that is according to privacy of users and the app, if not you will get privacy restriction message. I want to achieve the same in JavaScript, which is fine from the API point of view, but at the same time I cannot exploit the API key and secret in frontend, because then everyone could basicaly do everything with the app and what it owns

Answer (score 0):

You can make it harder, but you can't really secure it.

You can have them register the pages from which they are going to make the requests, and check that the request originates from an authorized origin when checking authentication.  Not perfect, as this can be faked, but harder for a casual user.

Or they can proxy through a server, but this does not help much since they need to secure access to their proxy.

Comment: Yes I have thought about adding the domain from which the request is coming from, since I do store the domain together with api key and secret (when the credentials are created, user has to fill the domain), but as you said it is not really hard to fake it. Junior programmer in my other company could fake that and that is enough for me to be unsecure.

Comment: Right :)  If the key gets abused, you can always reissue a new one.

Comment: In all likelihood, most requests would come from the same ip, not a web page, so you could also have a black list for ips.  Again, not perfect, just making it harder.

Comment: Commenting here since I can't comment on the question.  Issuing some expiring token as Austin suggested is interesting, but only works if you have a server where you can obtain this securely, not if you want to do everything client side (including chrome extensions)

Comment: I think the credit should go to @TildalWave ;) Im gonna comment on his comment

Comment: sorry, I meant @TildalWave in my previous comment.